# how to maintain a Home Button Presistent state of an app in Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

i am working on my App. in between i pressed the Home button on the device. my app will go to the background tasks. After that i long press the home button it will show my app as a persistent state. i.e where and what i had done in my app. But i click my app in the directory window it restarts my app. i want to do if my app is in the background tasks it will wake up else it will start. how to achieve that? Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do that Android will call:

- `onRestart()`
- `onStart()`
- `onResume()`

You can override that methods in order to do what you need. I wouldn't recommend it, though.

Remember that if the device needs memory, it will kill your process and when you open your app again Android will call the `onCreate()` method of your Activity.

Check the [Activity's lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife).